# Do sentences two and three convey the exact meaning as the first given sentence?

Tags: sentence-choice

> 1) I wonder how you came up with that.

Do both the following sentences convey the exact same meaning as the one used above? Are they both grammatically correct?

> 2) How you came up with that, I wonder.
>
> 3) How did you come up with that, I wonder.

Comment: #2 is not idiomatic.

Comment: Agreed with @TRomano - English word order is usually Subject-Verb-Object; in this case *I* is the subject, *wonder* is the verb, and *how you came up with that* is the object.  It is possible to reorder them for rhetorical effect or emphasis (for example, ["One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. **How he got into my pajamas I'll never know.**"](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/g/grouchomar128462.html)) but in general it's not idiomatic to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The third one isn't grammatically correct. If you don't have a question mark (and thus don't have a question), you **can't** use the **[subject–auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions)**.

> How you came up with that, I wonder.

Is correct, and might have a slight change of tone. To me, it adds disbelief and a somewhat condescending tone to the sentence by emphasizing **I wonder** at the end of the sentence, after a comma.

For the last one, you could say:

> How did you come up with that? I wonder.

Which, to me again, conveys a similar tone of condescending disbelief.